# What is the role of .gradle .idea gradle folders in an Android project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I could not find any resource explaining the need/purpose of .gradle .idea gradle folders in an android project. Can anyone explain in layman terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explaining the `.idea` folder is simple: Android Studio is the development IDE - internally it bases on the same IDE framework as IntelliJ and IntelliJ uses the `.idea` folder to store all IDE related projects settings. For example which files are open, how the different UI elements has been configured, the run configurations,...

The `.gradle` directory on the other side stores for each used gradle version temporary files. Usually it contains cached files and lock files that make sure that two gradle instances runing at the same time don't conflict with each-other.
This means that usually you can delete such files without consequences - gradle will rebuild them if needed.